# DUDA SOBRE CONTROL SELECT EN PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

HOLA A TODOS NECESITO SABER COMO PUEDO LLAMAR DATOS DE UN CAMPO EN MYSQL A UN CONTROL SELECT EN PHP. EJEMPLO TENGO MI TABLA TALLERES Y NECESITO CARGAR NOMBRE Y EL ID PERO AL MISMO MODO QUIERO QUE ESE FORMULARIO TAMBIEN SE PUEDA ACTUALIZAR ES DECIR TRAR LA INFORMACION AL CONTROL SELECT DE ACUERDO A SU ID, ALGUIEN ME PUEDE AYUDAR SOY NUEVO EN PHP. MI CODIGO PERO NO ME CARGA CUANDO QUIERO ACTUALIZAR.

```
<select class="form-control" id="taller" name="taller" value="<?php echo $alm->__GET('taller'); ?>">
          <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
          <?php
            $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM tbtaller");
            while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              echo '<option value="'.$valores['id'].'">'.$valores['nombre'].'</option>';
            }
          ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Verificaste que la consulta trae datos? Puedes poner un `var_dump($valores);` dentro del `while` para verificarlo. Tampoco se entiende a qué te refieres con *actualizar*. Y, considera usar adecuadamente mayúsculas y minúsculas, un texto todo en mayúscula es de muy mal gusto.

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y cambiarlas mayusculas por minusculas, parece que estas gritando

Answer (score 0):

lo que quise es mostrar mis datos de mi tabla en mysql atravez de un select y esto es lo que hice, derrepente a alguien le sirva.

```
<select class="form-control" name="taller" required>
                    <option value="">Seleccione Taller</option>
                    <?php
                      $query = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM tbtaller");
                        while($d=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                          if($d['id']==$alm->__GET('taller')){ 
                            echo '<option value="'.$d['id'].'" selected>'.$d['abreviatura'].'</option>';
                          }else{
                            echo '<option value="'.$d['id'].'">'.$d['abreviatura'].'</option>';
                          }
                        }
                    ?>
                  </select>
```